# Remove the Nth specified character from a line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log file with lines like this:

```
06:06:48.531 9: 157 2492
06:06:49.331 10: 147 2812
...
```

I need to remove *only* the 3rd '**:**' on all lines, so that the outcome would be:

```
06:06:48.531 9 157 2492
06:06:49.331 10 147 2812
...
```

Comment: `sed -e 's/://3'`

Comment: i'd wrong idea about the number in the end of command (3) , i though it the total replaced characters , but it's the Nth character , +1 cuonglm :)

Comment: If you change the question, you should begin a new question.

Comment: @cuonglm, if you could post an _Answer_ with your comment above I will rate it as this is for me the most elegant solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIXLY:

```
sed -e 's/://3' <file
```

Answer (score 1):

the 3rd ':' is followed by space , which make it different to others !

```
sed -i 's/: / /g' logfile
```

Comment: The `g` is not necessary. If there are several `:␣`, then they would all get removed...

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution:

```
awk '{ print(gensub(/:/,"",3,$0)) }' logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The long version (using a method which can be very useful when one gets tired and doesn't want to think too much...):

```
sed -e 's/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):/\1:\2:\3/'
```